# MYSQL: Left Join and limit appearence to one using group concat

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a sql like this:

```
SELECT TASKID, TSK_STATUSID, TSK_CODE, TSK_TITLE, TSK_REF_NO, TSK_DESCRIPTION, STS_NAME, COALESCE(USR_NAME, 'None') AS TUSERNAME 
FROM T_TASK_REQUEST 
LEFT JOIN T_STATUS ON T_STATUS.STATUSID=T_TASK_REQUEST.TSK_STATUSID 
LEFT JOIN T_TASK_USER ON TUS_TASKID = TASKID 
LEFT JOIN T_USER ON USERID = TUS_USERID 
LEFT JOIN T_PROJECT ON T_PROJECT.PROJECTID=T_TASK_REQUEST.PROJECTID 
WHERE TSK_STATUSID='1' AND T_TASK_REQUEST.PROJECTID='2' ORDER BY TASKID DESC LIMIT 10
```

And Current result is like this[image]

How do i group concat the **TASKID** into 1 row and **TUSERNAME** result as: boon|danny|jack|goh|ncc

separate by **|** ?

View full size IMG here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXH3g.jpg

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COALESCE(USR_NAME, 'None') SEPARATOR '|')` and add GROUP BY cols....

Answer (score 0):

The exact working SQL after modify is:

```
SELECT TASKID, TSK_STATUSID, TSK_CODE, TSK_TITLE, TSK_REF_NO, TSK_DESCRIPTION, STS_NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COALESCE(USR_NAME, 'None') SEPARATOR '|') AS TUSERNAME 
FROM T_TASK_REQUEST 
LEFT JOIN T_STATUS ON T_STATUS.STATUSID=T_TASK_REQUEST.TSK_STATUSID 
LEFT JOIN T_TASK_USER ON TUS_TASKID = TASKID 
LEFT JOIN T_USER ON USERID = TUS_USERID 
LEFT JOIN T_PROJECT ON T_PROJECT.PROJECTID=T_TASK_REQUEST.PROJECTID 
WHERE TSK_STATUSID='1' AND T_TASK_REQUEST.PROJECTID='2' 
GROUP BY TASKID
ORDER BY TASKID DESC LIMIT 10
```

thanks to @John Woo